# Dynamically populate bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap-select(https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) and below code to populate select picker dynamically. But this code is not working. Could you please let me know what is missing or what needs to be done to get it worked. If you have any other alternative please let me know. I need an select to be populated dynamically and width can be fixed. Ajax based search and population is nice to have.

I have also tried refresh option but it is adding one more drop down along with the added one.

```
if(!$.isEmptyObject(data)){
    var select = '<li><select class="input-sm selectpicker" data-size="5" data-width="100px" onchange="javascript:loadOragAttributeDataForHierarchy(this);" id="orgid">';
    select +='<option value="-">--select--</option>';
    $.each(data,function(key,value){
        select+='<optgroup label="'+key+'">';
        $.each(value, function(k, v) {                  
            select+='<option value="'+v.value +'">'+v.name+'</option>';
        });
        select+='</optgroup>';
    });

    select+='</select></li>';

    $('#'+elementid).append(select);
    $('#orgid').selectpicker();
}
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle or paste your HTML?

Comment: this is part of the code. On the event of another element, this code will populate the select. It's within a method

Comment: .selectpicker() is a function defined under bootstrap-select lib, i think  replacing $('#orgid').selectpicker(); with $('.selectpicker').selectpicker(); will do a trick, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/girish28892/RUAS4/478/

Comment: $('#orgid').selectpicker('refresh'); worked for me. There was some other issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: great indeed :)